# MapBox swift 3 api

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapbox

I use MapBox api swift 2.3 and reading geojson. But after swift 3 dont work began to upgrade.

Swift 2.3 examples; its work

```
 for location in locations {
nate2D(latitude: location[1].doubleValue, longitude: location[0].doubleValue)

coordinates.append(coordinate)
}
```

Swift 3.0 dont work

```
if let feature = feature as? NSDictionary {
    if let geometry = feature["geometry"] as? NSDictionary {
        if geometry["type"] as? String == "Polygon" {
            var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
            if let locations = geometry["coordinates"] as? NSArray {
                for location in locations {
                    for i in (0 ..< (location as AnyObject).count)
                    {
                        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ???, longitude: ???)
                        coordinates.append(coordinate)
                    }
                }
            }

            let shape = MGLPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                [unowned self] in
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(shape)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75RE9.png)

Comment: Please show us the response of your coordinates.

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location[1].doubleValue, location[0].doubleValue)  (Examples  (41, 28))

Comment: Add terminal screen shot

Comment: What I am telling you is print the response/ output of geometry Dictionary or locations array.

Comment: how to write format ""let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ???, longitude: ???)
                        coordinates.append(coordinate)""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ' s correct answer

```
       for location in locations {


                                            for i in (0 ..< (location as AnyObject).count)
                                            {

                                               let a =  locations[0] as? NSArray

                                                let b = a?[i] as? NSArray
                                                var c = b?[0]
                                                print(c);
                                                 let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: b?[1] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: b?[0] as! CLLocationDegrees)

                                                coordinates.append(coordinate)

                                            }


                                        }
```